# Using PHP and IFrame to override style of webpage locally

Tags: php, css, iframe, local

I have an account with [Simple In/Out](https://www.simpleinout.com).  We have 50+ employees and display their statuses (In/Out of office) on a TV at the receptionist desk.  However  we can't fit all of the employees on the screen without scrolling.

Simple In/Out provides very limited styling to how the list is shown. With CSS I could remove dead space and visually improve the list.

At first I would inspect element and make a few changes however the screen would get refreshed and all changes lost.

I am trying to simply make a .html page that displays an iFrame of the List with Local CSS edits.

The list url is simpleinout.com/list- login and the list displays.

The following 2 files display the page and an appended CSS file with changes however if I click anywhere else the CSS file is removed.

```
simple.html:

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe  src="http://localhost/~JohnHarbert/simple.php" style="border: 0" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>


simple.php:

<?php

$content = file_get_contents('http://www.simpleinout.com/list');
$content = str_replace('<head>','<base href="https://www.simpleinout.com/" /><head>',   $content);
$content = str_replace('</head>','<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/~JohnHarbert/style.css" /></head>', $content);

echo $content;

?>
```

Again.  The code does append the css file on the initial load(It adds it just before ).  But when I click to display list. The css file is no longer added inside the Iframe.

You're help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the web developer behind Simple In/Out.

The easiest way to fit more users on your screen would be to use the font/column controls in the upper right.  Once you've entered Full Screen mode, click on the gear icon in the upper right.  It will allow you to choose anywhere from 2 to 6 columns of users and you can adjust the font size to fit more on the screen.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I need to also customize the colors.  The status is gray on a black background for fullscreen mode.  Did you build the site on Wordpress?

Comment: Nope, Simple In/Out is built from the ground up.  If you need to customize the colors, likely your best option would be something like GreaseMonkey, which would allow you to do this at the browser level.

Comment: GreaseMonkey for the WIN!  Thanks. So Simple. No pun.

Comment: BTW: Simple In/Out now supports background and text color options for Full Screen Mode right in the company settings, no hacking required.  You can even upload a company logo.